# I try to make a complex sql request

Tags: sql, request

I try to make a complex sql request, please help me.

I have this request :

```
SELECT count(id_order) as NbOrders
FROM ORDER
WHERE order.state = 3 
    and order.source = 1;
```

But, I would like have a inscription with this condition too in the same request :

```
WHERE order.state != 3 
    AND order.source != 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE 
           WHEN order.state = 3 AND order.source = 1 THEN 1 
           ELSE 0 END) AS equal,
       SUM(CASE 
           WHEN order.state <> 3 AND order.source <> 1 THEN 1 
           ELSE 0 END) AS different
FROM order;
```

This gives you the count where `order.state = 3 AND order.source = 1` in the first column and 
the count where `order.state <> 3 AND order.source <> 1` in the second column.

Comment: Im glad you understood what was being asked :)
I guess the column `order.etat` was a spelling mistake...